# Dynamic array of rectangle in c++.cli Windows form

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am Making a snake game in c++/CLI Windows Form..
and
 I need your help to make 

**Dynamic (System::Drawing::Rectangle) array that  increase array->Length  when i call some event** ...

Inshort is it possible to increase the length of array when i call some event...

Comment: You should be using one of the resizable collections in `System::Collections::Generic` or `System::Collections`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: no, there is no automatic way to increase the length of an array

Array must have their length specified at creation time.

So, you really have two choices:

1. When you want to increase the length of your array, create a new array and copy the old array to it
2. Use one of the other collection classes. The List class acts is pretty close, you can use the [] operators, plus you can insert new items anywhere (beginning, middle, end), and it works with the foreach loop. And, you can use the ToArray method to get an array if you absolutely need to

I would only recommend using option 1 only if you are going to resize the array VERY infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Dynamic arrays, but judging by your post you have a little wile before you are up to that in skill.

But yes it is possible if you use dynamic arrays/memory.

I hope that helps I wont write out how to make your own dynamic array because it would take to long to write out.